# Missing disc when installing windows 7

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-installer

when I was installing windows 7 on my new bought computer it asked me on which disc I would like to install the OS on, either the 1 tera byte disc or the ssd disc, I chose to install it on the ssd disc. But now when I have installed the OS, the 1 tera byte disc isn't visible in "my computer" and I don't know how to access it, I didn't do anything strange in the installation, that by the way is idiot secure.

So my question, what do you think have happend and how do you believe that this issue is solved?

Regards Anders

Comment: Next time, use http://superuser.com/

Comment: Might get more answers on superuser.com

Answer (score 1):

Wrong site, but ok. You will need to go into Control Panel, System and Security, Administrative tools and open up Computer Management, select Disk Management, and format the disk. You can do so by right clicking the 1tb and selecting format

Comment: Yep, but create a partition first!